# File not downloaded m3u

Tags: python

I created a python script to download m3u file unfortunately the file and empty

```
import os, sys, re, time, os

LINKFILE= '/tmp/link'
M3UPATH= '/tmp/IPTVWORLD73.m3u'

link = 'http://xtremity.tv/get.php?username=5686626928&password=7936628346&type=m3u_plus&output=ts'

os.system('curl -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  --limit-rate 100K    -n -s -k -Lbk -A -k -m 8 -m 52 %s -o %s > /dev/null 2>&1' % (url, M3UPATH))
```

I tried that but still the same problem the file is empty

```
import urllib.request

#wget.download(url, M3UPATH)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, M3UPATH)
```

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't discard the `curl` output so that you can see any error messages? Once you fix the "url is undefined" error, you'd see that you get a HTTP 404 error -- file not found.

Comment: On the other hand when I put the url on mozilla firefox at the end of a moment the file and download successfully...

Comment: So... is that a real username+password combo you just posted here? If so... probably a really good idea to change the password.

Answer (score 0):

### Reproduced with curl on shell

A simple curl to test for the response-headers `-I` showed OK:

```bash
curl -I "http://xtremity.tv/get.php?username=5686626928&password=7936628346&type=m3u_plus&output=ts"
```

Output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2022 20:11:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
```

Then downloading to a file using `-o <file>` has written 139M to disk successfully:

```bash
curl -o "Downloads/SO_xtremityTv.ts" "http://xtremity.tv/get.php?username=5686626928&password=7936628346&type=m3u_plus&output=ts"
```